# Agora flexible classroom chat widget handler in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, agora.io, agora-implementation

I have implemented and launch **Agora Felexible Classroom** in my iOS app. everything works fine.
there is a chat module that I want to get access to Send button callback function to send a message to socket.io

I knew there was a onSendMessage () function, but I can't access it. maybe I need to inherit from a specific class or import something

I would be grateful if anyone could help me

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 imports: AgoraUIKit_iOS and AgoraRtcKit.
If this will not help you, maybe you should update the pods.
Also can check: https://cocoapods.org/pods/AgoraUIKit_iOS it may help